# Invoking thread with a single parameter

Tags: objective-c

```
-(BOOL)KickTimer:(unsigned short) wTimerIds
    {
        operation1 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:
                                         @selector(insertEvent:) object:pEvent];
    }

-(void)insertEvent:(stRs232Timer*)pEvent
{
 //stmts;
}
```

I could not invoke this `function.Is` this way of invoking a thread with single parameter is correct.

### EDITED

```
pEvent = (stRs232Timer*)[[m_cAppIdMap objectForKey:[NSNumber   
                          numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerIds]]bytes];
```

**Warning:**

```
Warning: passing argument 3 of 'initWithTarget:selector:object:' 
from incompatible pointer type
```

Answer (score 1):

From [NSOperation class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Operation objects are non-concurrent by default. In a non-concurrent operation, the operation’s task is performed synchronously—that is, the operation object does not create a separate thread on which to run the task. Thus, when you call the start method of a non-concurrent operation directly from your code, the operation executes immediately in the current thread. By the time the start method of such an object returns control to the caller, the task itself is complete.

Consider using:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(insertEvent:) toTarget:self withObject:pEvent];
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining about NSThreads.If i do the same as you have told me to do i'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.I dont know why that happens.The invocation works fine for NSobjectsother than pEvent.I then missed to call [queue addOperation:operation1]; .But even though its not invoking.

Comment: where are you getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS? if `pEvent` is, as it seems, visible in global scope, you may also pass nil to `detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:` and access `pEvent` directly from second thread.

Comment: When the thread gets callled i'm getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.pEvent is a local scope and cant be made as a global one as it has dependencies.Is there any other way to invoke it.

Comment: Probably that's not the cause, but remember that, in the second thread, you have to instantiate a `NSAutoreleasePool` and `drain` it at the end of the thread/method. Besides, may you post the function you detach?