# Main thread doesn't respond while NSOperationQueue is running its task

Tags: iphone, multithreading, nsoperationqueue

I use `NSOperationQueue` to create `UIImage`s in the background,
upon image creation, main thread gets notified and set the image to a view.

While it works and all, main thread is not responding as I hoped while the `NSOperationQueue` is working.

The point of using thread here is to let UI be responsive to user interactions.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: please don't put tags in your titles, it's redundant with the tags.

Comment: Could you add some code?

Answer (score 0):

check [Invoking thread with a single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226415/invoking-thread-with-a-single-parameter/6226531#6226531)